# I’m having a tough time trying to program 2 fsr sensors

Tags: arduino-uno

[image: This is how everything is connected]Can anyone help me please?
I’m having a tough time trying to program 2 fsr sensors.                                                                                                           The logic behind the code is that if you were to squeeze both sensors at the same time it will print out an output on the serial monitor acknowledging that both sensors have been squeezed?                     I have got only one to work by using this code:

```
/* FSR simple testing sketch. 

Connect one end of FSR to power, the other end to Analog 0.
Then connect one end of a 10K resistor from Analog 0 to ground 

For more information see www.ladyada.net/learn/sensors/fsr.html */

int fsrPin = 0;     // the FSR and 10K pulldown are connected to a0
int fsrReading;     // the analog reading from the FSR resistor divider

void setup(void) {
  // We'll send debugging information via the Serial monitor
  Serial.begin(9600);   
}

void loop(void) {
  fsrReading = analogRead(fsrPin);  

  Serial.print("Analog reading = ");
  Serial.print(fsrReading);     // the raw analog reading

  // We'll have a few threshholds, qualitatively determined
  if (fsrReading < 10) {
    Serial.println(" - No pressure");
  } else if (fsrReading < 200) {
    Serial.println(" - Light touch");
  } else if (fsrReading < 500) {
    Serial.println(" - Light squeeze");
  } else if (fsrReading < 800) {
    Serial.println(" - Medium squeeze");
  } else {
    Serial.println(" - Big squeeze");
  }
  delay(1000);
}
```

So what would be the correct code in order to get two sensors to work at the same time?

Comment: Do you get ANY output on the serial monitor? If so can you share it?

Answer (score 1):

Call your second FSR "fsr2" connect it to analog pin A1 and add to your existing code. Sort of like this:

```
int fsrPin = 0, fsr2Pin = 1;     // the FSR and 10K pulldown are   connected to a0
int fsrReading, fsr2Reading;     // the analog reading from the FSR resistor divider

void setup(void) {
  // We'll send debugging information via the Serial monitor
  Serial.begin(9600);   
}

void loop(void) {
  fsrReading = analogRead(fsrPin);
  delay(5);
  fsr2Reading = analogRead(fsr2Pin);


  Serial.print("Analog reading = ");
  Serial.print(fsrReading);     // the raw analog reading
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(fsr2Reading);
```

Comment: Just started on forum, don't know how to format code yet, sorry.

Comment: There's a `{}` button in the editor.